# Show segment addresses in gdb

Tags: assembly, linker, gdb, segment

This [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=165&v=1S0aBV-Waeo) shows the layout of the virtual memory of a program, which includes the following segments from a high memory address to a low memory address.

- kernel
- stack (grows from high addresses to low addresses)
- heap (grows from low addresses to high addresses)
- data
- text

Is the arrangement of these segments always so? Are they independent of what computer architecture a computer uses?

To inspect the address of each segment in gdb, could anybody show me how to do it?
Take the following C program as an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

Comment: `/proc/<PID>/maps` is somewhat relevant on Linux systems, to see the different mappings.  But data and BSS can be part of the same extent, IIRC, going past the end of the file-backed part.  Usually the layout of segments relative to each other is fixed at link-time, according to the linker script.  (Almost always you just use the default `ld` linker script unless you're linking an OS kernel image, instead of a normal executable.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is the arrangement of these segments always so?

No. For one thing, modern programs use multiple threads, which means there are multiple stacks. For another, modern `malloc` implementations use `mmap`, so "the heap" is not a single contiguous space, but a collection of disjoint arenas. Shared libraries' `.text` and `.data` are also sprinkled randomly, and may be between heap arenas.

> Are they independent of what computer architecture a computer uses?

No. Certain architectures use stack which grows up (towards higher addresses), though these architectures are currently rare.

> To inspect the address of each segment in gdb, could anybody show me how to do it?

GDB doesn't have any special support for examining segments. On Linux, `/proc/$pid/maps` will show you current mappings. Once you know the base address of any given segment, you can examine memory at that address using the "normal" GDB `x` command.